# setActivityForResult() in Custom Adapter Class

Tags: android

I have a Custom Adapter class which extends BaseAdapter. This class fills out a GridView with different dates using an Inflater. Within this Class, I have an onClick method. When any date is clicked, it currently brings the user to a different Activity. That part works fine.

I'd like to get some data back to the clicked view in my Custom Adapter class. Does anyone why I am not able to implement a startActivityForResult() method within my onClick? I passed the Context from my MainActivity in to the Custom Adapter Class. The picture below shows the only methods available. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Thats because the Adapter cant Accept the result. Thats the job of an activity. Your Activity has to override the method onActivityResult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Context` and `Activity` classes are not the same, though they can perform similar functions in some cases. Only the `Activity` class has the `startActivityForResult` method, so you should be using a reference to that instead of to a `Context`.

Answer (score 1):

I am using a custom adapter in a fragment, and for that, I pass `Fragment` object in constructor of custom adapter. So, in your case passing an instance of `Activity` will work.

or, a cleaner solution will be to create a interface in your adapter. Like this -

```
public interface FeedItemClickListener {
        void onMyItemClick(View view);
}
```

and implement this interface in activity you are using your adapter. Override it's function like this -

```
@Override
    public void onMyItemClick(View view) {
//Do your work here.
}
```

and you are good to go.